# How can I link a page to an application in order to get real time updates from the page?

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I would like to get real time updates from my pages, and I wonder what is the right way to do so, When subscribing to a page, it (funnily) works, but page events are not sent.
Subscribing to an app, sends only the user feed, not pages feed. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on Facebook help:
http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=172925542764476

Comment: Your answer is a *stub* and may eventually be deleted. Please provide [more substantive details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72002/141525) rather than just posting a link.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: From Facebook link: 
How can I add apps to my Facebook Page?
To make the page that you admin more useful and successful, we encourage you to add compatible apps developed on Facebook Platform. 

To add an app to your Facebook Page, first go to the App About Page for the app you'd like to add. If the app is available to be added to your page, you'll see an Add to Page link on the lower left-hand column. 

Note that certain apps may not be available for pages. If you have any questions about those apps, please use the Contact Developer link in the App About Page to inquire.